# How to draw a drawing of thousands of lines efficiently?

Tags: android, achartengine

I need to draw a picture representing a profile of altitudes in a way that an android is drawing the image in a speedily way. This is a altitude profile compose of 50.000 heights or even more. I am using AChartEngine but for this huge amount of line is not very fast to draw and zoom. Is there any other lib suitable for that propose? Do you think a .svg drawing would be better?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What about OpenGL either in C or Java? I'd recommend using the batch methods that accept arrays so that you invoke a native method only once, and recycle any objects you might create. The same could probably be achieved using a hardware accelerated Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any existing libs doing what you want. if you want to code it yourself, here are my thoughts. the difficulty mainly lies in zoom because otherwise you can pre-compute the entire image. I guess the best method is hierarchical pre-computing. for example, you can pre-compute:

```
pre-compute(region r)
    l = the list of lines intersecting with r
    if l has less than T1 number of lines:
        pre-compute the image in r with l;
    else 
        divide r evenly into four subregions r1,r2,r3,r4
        pre-compute(r1)
        pre-compute(r2)
        pre-compute(r3)
        pre-compute(r4)
```

The list of lines intersecting with any region can also be cached. You can cache the pre-computed images and line lists in a quad tree. If you add/remove lines, you can also incrementally do it in the tree. then when you draw, you use the following algorithm:

```
 draw(region r):
     if r is a subset of a pre-computed region:
         draw r using the pre-computed image
     else
         if r is smaller than T2:
             l = the list of lines intersecting with r
             if l has less than T1 number of lines: 
                 draw r with l
                 return 
         divide r evenly into four regions r1, r2, r3, r4
         draw(r1)
         draw(r2)
         draw(r3)
         draw(r4)
```

the quirk in this algorithm might be in picking the right threshold T1,T2, which you might be able to avoid by making the algorithm cache-oblivious. please let me know if you have any further questions.